# Getting input values from tables with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

Right now, my HTML code looks like so:

```
<div id="register">
<table class="tab2">
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="confirmemail" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And to get the values from the inputs via jQuery, I have to do this:

```
$("#email").live('focusout', function() {
    email = $(this).val();
});
$("#confirmemail").live('focusout', function() {
    confirmemail = $(this).val();
});
```

I know there are better solutions to perform this (as my solution *works*, but is messy since there's way more than two inputs), but they won't work for me. I'd like to use something like

```
$("#email").val();
```

and just retrieve the value as it's needed, rather than storing it to a variable. The issue is that whenever I run that code, it always returns an empty string. What would be the reason for that?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the values are being used after a click event is ran, like so:

```
$("#dialog_next").live('click', function() {
```

When I run the $("#email").val() code after that, it returns an empty string.

Comment: if the code above functions properly ,then `$("#email").val();` should also work as intended. Make sure that you execute this snippet at the right moment.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it runs after a button click, Rob. Updated my post.

Comment: Your code should still work. Can you offer a link to the actual page?

Comment: @PuppyKevin How is your page different from the fiddle I posted which works?  (Remember, jsfiddle auto adds to the ondomready state.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:  This fiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yt8pK/

I expect this issue has something to do with when the code is actually run.  Since I can't see the problem code I can only guess.  For example if you had like this:

```
 $(function () {
     var email = $("#email").val();

     function string getEmail() {
        return email;
     }

     ... (later you call getEmail to look at the value)

 });
```

It would fail as the variable email is set before user input.

Code like this would work:

```
 $(function () {

     function string getEmail() {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        return email;
     }

     ... (later you call getEmail to look at the value)

 });
```

What did your code which failed look like?

Comment: My code looks like this:

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dialog_next").live('click', function() {
    alert($("#email").val());
}
}

Which, for some reason, still is returning nothing. Also, #dialog_next is wrapped in a #dialog div, and the table is wrapped in a #dialog_contents div.

Comment: @puppykevin - Well check your code for typos (eg dailog) and then start changing the working fiddle to look more and more like your code and find when it breaks.  fiddles are a debug tool.

Comment: @puppykevin - also the code you posted in the comment above is wrong... it is missing a few `);` so maybe you just have a javascript syntax error.